# How to wait for return value and subscribe to it in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, subscribe

I've encountered a problem while developing app in Ionic. I'm executing a query on the database using database provider and it is fine but it is probably called asynchronous because I get undefined.

After some checks and other logic I'm returning value from the database:

```
this.databaseProvider.getValueFor(saved.id)
    .then(data => {
           return data;
    });
```

Is there any way to return data to Observable and subscribe to it? I'm quite new to Angular2 and don't know all concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Observable.fromPromise**][1]` method to convert promise to Observable & then subscribe to Observable to retrieve data from it.

```
SomeMethod(){
   return Observable.fromPromise(this.databaseProvider.getValueFor(saved.id))
}

//Usage
this.SomeMethod().subscribe(data => {
   console.log("data", data)
})
```

Comment: 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PromiseLike<{}>

Comment: hello i am using angular auth client oidc  this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().subscribe();
 this method is provided by oidc library how to wait for such subscribe until complete. I can't convert it to promise because it is in library

Answer (score 0):

Observables are lazy so you need to subscribe it to get the data from it.

```
this.databaseProvider.getValueFor(saved.id)
  .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data); //response
});
```

`getValueFor(id): Observable<any> {
   const url = 'http://yourAPI/'+id; 
   return this.http.get<any>(url) 
     .pipe( 
           map((res: any) => res.json()), 
           catchError(e => this.handleError(e)) 
    ); 
}`

Comment: what if I am calling a HTTP request inside a service layer and need to wait for the response from the request and do some thing with it in the component?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. You just need to return the  response of HTTP call. Take a look in below code snippet
`getData(url): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(url)
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => res.json()),
                catchError(e => this.handleError(e))
            );
    }`

Comment: So, I will be writing the subscribe like getData(url).subscribe() right?